# How to keep my program generating alert when the array is set with lowers values

Tags: java, swing

I developed a program to monitor a router traffic when the traffic is below a threshold my java program triggers an alarm. Every 30 seconds (Timer)I get a traffic value from the router via snmp and I store each value in array. My problem is when there is an outage the value showed in the textfiled is +/- 0.0 and the textfiled color become red but after some minute the color of textfield become green and value of textfiled still low. 
Could you help me please to manage this condition and to keep my textfield red or yelow until the traffic recover. Below is my code :

```
//sum of the array    
public float sumArray(float arr[]){
    int j;
    float sum = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
        sum = sum + arr[j];
    }
    return sum;
}
// method generating alert  
public void blade1() {
     //arr1 to made average of valCalOut = valFinalOut
 arr1 = new float[3];
     //arr2 calculate the threhsold it's the average of valCalOut
 arr2 = new float[10];  
        // fill the arr1 with valCalOut
        if ( i1 <= arr1.length ){           
            arr1[i1] = valCalOut;
            i1 ++;

         }else{
             i1 =0;
             arr1B1[i1] = valCalOut;
             i1++;
         }
        //sum arr1 to get valFinalOut
        if (index1 <= 3){
                valFinalOut = sumArray(arr1) / index1 ;
                index1++;
            }else{
                valFinalOut = sumArray(arr1) / 3 ;
          }
        // fill arr2 with valCalOut 
        if ( i2 < arr2.length ){            
            arr2[i2] = valCalOut;
            i2 ++;

         }else{
             i2 =0;
             arr2[i2] = valCalOut;
             i2++;
         }  
                    // sum arr2 to calculate the threshold(is average of valCalOut)
        if (index2 <= 10){
            averageVal = sumArray(arr2) / index2 ;
            index2++;
        }else{
            averageVal = sumArray(arr2) / 10;
        }

        threshold = averageVal - (averageVal * dropRatio);


    txtout.setText(Float.toString(valFinalOut));
        txtav.setText(Float.toString(averageVal));
    txtth.setText(Float.toString(threshold));


                if (valFinalOut < threshold ) {
                    if (txtout.getBackground() == Color.YELLOW) {
                                            //btnreset pressed txtout turned yellow
                            stopAlarm();
                    } else {
                         btnreset.setEnabled(true);
                         txtout.setBackground(Color.RED);
                         btnreset.setEnabled(true);
                         playAlarm();
                         textArea.append(dateTime()+" : Traffic dropped, Bandwith : " + valFinalOut + " Mbps, Average : "+averageVal+  " Mbps, Threshold : " +threshold+ " Mbps,  Please check ! \n "); 
                                                }
                } else {
                            txtout.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    btnreset.setEnabled(false);
                }       
        }
```

Comment: As amazing as the other posters are here, they don't have a crystal balls.  Some sample code would be helpful

Comment: I reduced my posted code

Comment: You'll get better results if you edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: This has to be some of the most difficult to decipher code I've seen in quite a while. Consider refactoring the class, cleaning up the code, and renaming your variables to use names that self-comment the code. If you still need our help, consider posting a small compilable and runnable program that illustrates the problem and that we have a prayer of understanding.

Comment: What happens when valFinalOut_B1 == threshold_B1? I'd start there

Comment: @MadProgrammer valFinalOut == threshold nothing happened. The threshold is the average values of the arr2 that has 10 elements and the valFinalOut is the average of the arr1 that has 3 element.

Comment: @Abs so eventually valFinalOut_B1 is going to be <= threashold_B1, no?  Once valFinalOut_B1 >= threashold_B1, you're fields turn green, no?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes right it turn green. I reduced my code again. Please note that both arr1 and arr2 are filled with same value valCalOut every 30 seconds and the value valCalOut change every 30 seconds because it reflect the actual router traffic.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I added some comment I hope it's helpful.

Comment: My code work fine if the the drop of traffic is quick i.e it recover after 2 or 3  minute but if the drop is more than +/- 6 min normaly the alarm should be there and txt color should still red or yellow but what's happened is that the color become green. it become green because the  valCalOut and threshold are calculated dyinamicly. my problem is in arr2 I need a way that the threshold dont become lower when the alarm is raised.

Comment: @Abs: you need to indent uniformly as well to allow that code to be readable. But just from the little I've seen consider re-writing it from scratch with more separation of concerns. Looks like you have methods and classes that are given too much responsibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I increased the average time by 30 min instead of 5 min so my array have more values and contains 60 values instead of 10 values. So now the alarm keep being red until the traffic really restored. Thanks for everyone.